# Replace HTML (stored in S3) text on particular class in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a stored html file in AWS S3. Now I want to modify the HTML's content on a particuler class. I am able to read the content but I could not replace the content.

```
if MCDS::Object.exists?(article_html)
        html_content = MCDS::Object.value(article_html)
        doc =  Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html_content)
        **doc.css("p.pubdate.online").text.to_s.gsub!("Published online before print August 19, 2014Published online before print August 19, 2014", "10")**

        url = MCDS::Object.save(s3_path_prefix(false), html_content, public: open_access?(content_type))
  else
        raise "HTML not found"
  end
```

How can I replace the content inside the HTML's P tag with class 'pubdate' and 'online'?

Answer (score 0):

using Jquery '.replaceWith()' http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Comment: I am not allowed to use jQuery. I want to do this in Rails.